# How to create UITabviewcontroller with Frame

Tags: ios5

i have a code for UItabviewcontroller using programmatically ,but how to creates its frame as i am using as subviews in my application where i required x,y width and height coordinates.

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

```
UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

UIView *v1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *v2 = [[UIView alloc] init];

vc1.title = @"vc1";
vc2.title = @"vc2";

tabBarController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];

self.view = tabBarController.view;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged your question with ios5, I suppose your app is only running on ios5. If I understand you right, you want to present the tabBarController in another view controllers view.

Prior to 5.0 this is not possible, without some very ugly hacks. But with iOS5.x there now is an API for that. Take a look at the UIViewController documentation at 'Implementing a Container View Controller'. You have to set the tabBarController as a child view controller of your current view controller. Than you can assign the frame you want it to have and simply add it to your View.